# Multiple actors for one use-case?

Tags: uml, actor, use-case

I have the following scenario that i would like to make it into a use-case called `CallHelp`:

- The patient needs assistance from a nurse.
- The patient presses on the Force Sensitive Resistor (FSR) at the bedside.
- The signal light at the bed side will be turned on.
- The alarm will sound at the counter.
- The web application will show indication of the bed number that calls for assistance.
- nurse attends to the patient’s request.
- The nurse clears the request on the web application.

However I only manage to get to this point so far and I am confused by the actor for the next few cases which i marked with `??` 
Use-Case:   CallHelp
Primary actor:  Patient (or Care system and Nurse too`???`)
Goal in context:    To call for assistance from the nurse in duty.
Preconditions:  The FSR is located at somewhere accessible by the patient.
Trigger:    The patient needs assistance from the nurse in duty.
Scenario:

- 1.Patient: presses on the FSR2.
- 2.Care system: turns on signal light at bedside `??`
- 3.Care system: sounds alarm at counter`??`
- 4.Care system: show indication on web app`??`
- 5.Nurse: attend to request`??`
- 6.Nurse: clear request`??`

Frequency of use:   Many times per day.
Channel to actor:   Via FSR sensor.

Is this allowable? Or how should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

That's because they are three separate use cases in (parentheses) with three actors [in square brackets].

[Patient] -> (Request Assistance) -> [Care System] -> (display alert) -> [Nurse] -> (Respond to alert)

A use case is always triggered by an actor action.

Also note that the middle three are sometimes not shown on diagram to simplify the view. You could have a full scenario diagram named "Patient Assistance" that would just contain the two border use cases from above.

[Patient] -> (Request Assistance)
[Nurse] -> (Respond to alert)

However, your use case realization diagrams (sequence, collaboration) would show the complete interaction between all the design elements.